# How to track a US K-1 visa application once USCIS has approved the I-129F?

Tags: usa, visa, uk-citizens

I'm applying for a K-1 USA visa from the UK. I was wondering how to track it beyond the USCIS. I know it goes to the NVC then goes to my local consulate. Is there any way to know online where I can track it? The USCIS part had an online case status, however the other parts don't seem to.

I want to track when it is received by the NVC and leaves the NVC and arrives at the London US Embassy.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want to find out?

Comment: @Karlson I've updated it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer myself, so I'll share it with everyone so they can find it too.

### When can I start tracking what happens after my NOA2 from the USCIS?

If you've been following the I-129F petition on the [USCIS Case Status](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/Dashboard/CaseStatus.do) tracker, then you will notice after the NOA2 is issued it doesn't really give you any more information. As soon as they NOA2 has been issued, and you receive the hard copy the odds are the NVC have received your petition too.

Now you can call them to find out your Visa Case number.

### Get your Visa Case Number

You need to call the [NVC](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/immigrate/nvc/nvc-contact-information.html) to get your Case Number as follows (waiting times can be long, and sometimes when busy the call may not go through or lines will drop). Both the petitioner and beneficiary can call. If you aren't in the USA, then you can make the [call for free using you Gmail](https://www.google.com/chat/voice/) account.

> **Phone Number:** +1 (603) 334-0700
>
> **Hours:** Monday through Friday from 7:00 AM to 12:00 AM (Eastern Time)

You need to have the following information to get the case number from the NVC, they may ask you for your NVC Case Number but explain that you are looking for it:

> USCIS Receipt Number (it is on the USCIS Notice of Action letters)
>
> Petitioner’s Full Name and Date of Birth
>
> Beneficiary’s Full Name and Date of Birth

### Track the Progress

Go to the [CEAC Visa Tracking](https://ceac.state.gov/CEACStatTracker/Status.aspx?) website, and enter the case number you got from the NVC.

You can track all the way from the NVC to your consulate receiving the I-129F petition, then you are ready to submit your part of the K-1 Visa application ([DS-160](https://ceac.state.gov/GenNIV/Default.aspx)).

### Sources

- [NVC and CEAC Status Tracker - Life as Mrs. Presson](http://www.mrspresson.com/immigration/129f-fiancee-petition-process/nvc-ceac-status-tracker/)
- [How do we
  track the NVC and Consulate progress - National Visa Center (Dept of
  State) - VisaJourney.com](http://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/418570-how-do-we-track-the-nvc-and-consulate-progress/)

Comment: You asked how to track a visa application, and then answered how to track a I-129F petition... -1 for not being able to ask the right question.

Comment: That part of the K-1 visa takes up 80% of the time. And most people will probably want to track that. The petition is part of the K-1 visa.

Comment: The petition is the petition. If you want to track the petition - ask about tracking the petition. Visa is what you get from the consulate based on that petition after it is approved. Being born is also part of the K1 visa - you can't get it without it, can you?

Comment: The petition is tracked by the USCIS, and after it is approved it goes to the NVC. So are you saying the visa process doesn't start until the consulate gets the petition?

Comment: the visa process doesn't start until you submit your visa application (DS-260). The foreigner applies for the visa. The 129F is what the US citizen applies for in order to get the foreigner the *right to apply* for the visa.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to check online for the status once the US Embassy gets it.  I have emailed them some questions and waiting for a reply now.  Beyond emailing them, there is no other way to find out information as when you call the main number, they direct you to "that branch" which is the Visa department.  You cannot call them.

Saying that the visa process doesn't start until you submit the DS160 is like splitting hairs and I think a bit erroneous.  Maybe semantics proves me wrong, but IMO the process starts when you submit to the USCIS because you CAN be denied at that level or be requested for RFE's, etc.  So, there is a process underway.  The K1 visa goes through the NVC quick, in a matter of days, to the US Embassy.  But other visas like work, petitioning for a family member, etc., will take weeks. It's always a good sign when you get to the US Embassy because it seems to me that you are essentially guaranteed an interview so long as your Packet 3 is submitted without any issue.  Then it's up to you at that point.  Just remember, their job is to make sure you have a sincere relationship so try and relax for the interview, unless you are trying to hide something which is not a good thing.